# Is typedef good for improving extendability

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int num;

int main() {
    num a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

In this way if I have to change this to float or a complex number by only changing one line of code.

Is this a good practice to do?

Comment: That seems like a very dangerous thing to do.

Comment: If your argument was that you could change the type to `unsigned` or `long` or another integer type, then you might be safer.  Changing from integer to floating point is a much bigger change, and correspondingly less safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that this style is useful

```
typedef int num;
```

Because `num` doesn't really mean much more and isn't imparting more information.  However, what you do see is segregating of types, like for instance

```
typedef long time_t
```

In this case, in the standard library, instead of using a long to represent a number of seconds, you use a `time_t`.  The standard allows implementors to pick different types for this within parameters (including floating point).

So, I would use typedef when you are reducing or specifying the meaning of the type and there are several choices that could meet that definition, and you don't want anyone to rely on the choice, but just the specification.

Answer (score 3):

The more interesting question is imho: Why would you want to change the type of the variables?

Because you have to keep in mind, that even numerical variables like int and float will behave differently in certain situations, and you would need to think of these situations whenever you use it as such a "generic" variable.

Thus I tend to say: No, it is not, as the side effects (especially once the project grows a little bit bigger than just a hello world ;)) play too big a role that you can just change the type

Comment: So if I want the ability to extend this "calculator", I would be better off with a wrapper classes for int float etc with a common abstract class?

Comment: Well since we're talking about C++ you have the great opportunity of function overloading and/or using templates. I think this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as though you are looking for [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29).

Comment: As in the example, I want all the numbers in the "calculator" to have the same type. Wouldn't template just make things more complicated? (e.g. type conversion?)

Comment: No, a template allows you to define an algorithm without committing to all the types of data involved. You can then instantiate the template in different ways with different types, e.g. float, complex etc. Sounds ideal for your calculator. I don't know what you mean by type conversion.

Comment: So making a template for adding numbers?

Comment: @Atomble Absolutely. That's a first class use case for templates.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, from an academic point of view, the answer might be "yes."  But in the real world, I find the answer is almost always "no," and here's why.

You say your ideal would be able to make a 1-line-of-code change to switch from `int`s to `float`s for example, and be done.  That would be nice, but for one reason or another, it's almost never actually possible.

Consider your actual example.  If you have code like this:

```
typedef int num;
...
num = 42;
...
if( 42 == num )
  // MAGIC HAPPENS
```

...and then you change it to:

```
typedef float num;
```

...the code will possibly compile, but it won't work correctly.  That is because you can't just compare floats to a constant variable for equality.  floats are imprecise, and the actual representation of `42f` might be something like `41.99999999999999` and then `if( 42f == num )` will return false.

Other examples are everywhere.  Using `typedef`s in STL collection classes, for example, are a prime example.  If you have this:

```
typedef vector<string> strings;
strings my_strings;
...
my_strings.find("hello");
```

...you can't just change the typedef to be a `list<string>` because `list` doesn't have a `find` member function.

In my experience, `typedef`s are most useful to save typing, thereby saving potential bugs, and also in making code more readable.  For example:

```
for( strings::iterator it = my_strings.begin(); it != my_strings.end(); ++it )
```

...is arguably more readable than:

```
for( vector<string>::iterator it = my_strings.begin(); it != my_strings.end(); ++it )
```

...especially when the container's type becomes increasingly complex.

Comment: The same is *always* true with changing implementations and loose specifications. Interfaces in principle suffer from the same problem, and yet they are hailed as the new coming of the Lord. I *still* agree instinctively with your assessment but I don’t think it’s entirely accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases `typedef` is important. There're some techniques like [Policy Clone](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Policy_Clone). Also take a look at reasons given by Herb Satter in [GotW #46](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/046.htm):

**Typeability**
Shorter names

**Readability**

```
typedef int (*Func)( int* );
Func t( int );
```

rather than

```
int ( *t(int) )( int* );
```

**Portability**

```
#if defined USING_COMPILER_A
  typedef __int32 Int32;
  typedef __int64 Int64;
#elif defined USING_COMPILER_B
  typedef int       Int32;
  typedef long long Int64;
#endif
```